# learning how to use Zapier

Tags: zapier

I wanted to learn how to use Zapier both personally and to provide clients with better support/information. Do you have any recommendations as to where to start? I looked on gitbook but could only find a sales pitch slide deck.

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best place for what you are trying to do, with that said your question may get removed but at the very least I can get you in the right direction.

[Zapier Support Docs](https://zapier.com/help) are useful for general knowledge.

Zapier also is really great about [replying to questions](https://zapier.com/app/contact-us) (I've done it alot).

Stack Overflow is best for when you are stuck (especially with code).

**How to get started:**

First learn how to make some simple zaps, just login and open up the console to do something simple like 'New Google Sheet Row when New Gmail Message'. Then learn to use the [Zapier Dev Tools](https://zapier.com/app/developer). The Dev tools are what people struggle with as you are coding an API with node.js (the UI interface uses JavaScript which is easier to start with). So what you will need to do is create a successful connection and test it out. Here is a [simple tutorial](https://platform.zapier.com/quickstart/introduction).

Learn by doing, and when you get stuck, come here and we can give you a hand.